# Is it possible to access the DOM element 'this' in a non-function parameter argument in a jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a potentially strange question about `this` and jQuery plugins

As I understand it, the following is a very basic jQuery plugin:

```
$.fn.clickclone = function(param){
    return this.click(function(){  
        param.apply(this);  
    });
};
```

(pretending that's a plugin that somehow extends `click()`.)

So, if I pass a function as an argument, it does what it needs to do and properly accesses `this` as a DOM node. Easy.

That's all clear to me.

What's not clear is, is there any way I could pass a *non-function* argument to the plugin and have it properly access `this` from the arguments? ie, could I configure the plugin to do something like this:

```
$("#foo").pluginname(["foo", $(this).text() ]);
```

Such that for:

```
<a href="/bar" id="foo">Bar</a>
```

It would properly pass an array to the plugin, with the second item in the array returning the value `Bar`?

I'm doing this, basically, to provide syntactic sugar for my plugin, where you can pass an array as a shortcut (in addition to using a normal callback function as the main functionality). Except, doing that, I lose access to use of `this`. Hence my dilemma.

**EDIT:** This is evil, but, it seems like one work around is to pass the argument as a string and then `eval` it. *Not* a workable solution for me, but, it illustrates what I'd like to be able to do:

```
$.fn.clickclone = function(param){
    return this.click(function(){ 
        if(typeof param === "function"){ 
            param.apply(this);
        }
        else if(typeof param[1] === "string"){
             console.dir("This is evil: " + eval(param[1]));
        }  
    });
};
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but why not just use a callback argument? Then you could use a closure that wraps up whatever you need.

Comment: `$("#foo").pluginname(["foo", $('#foo').text() ]);` is presumably not acceptable?

Comment: @El Yobo no; my use of an ID is misleading here, since I'm binding to a large number of DOM elements, rarely just one. Was just doing `#foo` to be illustrative.

Comment: @muistooshort For my use case, I'm using callbacks in the plugin to provide the main functionality, but I want try to provide some syntactic sugar, but inability to use `this` is a bit of a bummer.

Comment: Within the `pluginname()` function, you can use `$(this)`, but outside it there is no way to reference the matched elements.  If you want to be able to optionally specify the second argument, I would allow `.pluginname(["foo", null])` and fall back to using the `$(this).text()` within the plugin if the second argument is null.

Comment: @El Yobo that works for this particular simplification, but I'm looking for generic access to `this`. It sounds like you're saying its not possible.

Comment: Given my understanding, it's not possible; I can't really imagine any way it could be.  Domenic's answer below is more comprehensive and has some other workarounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no general way to do this without a function, since, in the purely mathematical sense, you are asking for a *function* of the input (that is, a function of `this`): something that depends on `this` in a certain way.

You could perhaps hack it with strings, like so, but you lose the flexibility of functions:

```
$.fn.alertMe = function (methodToAlert) {
    alert(this[methodToAlert]());
};

// usage:
$("#foo").alertMe("text");
$("#foo").alertMe("width");
```

And if you find using a function acceptable but the `this` syntax confusing, you can simply do the following:

```
$.fn.alertMe = function (alertGetter) {
    alert(alertGetter($(this));
};

// usage:
$("#foo").alertMe(function (x$) { return x$.text(); });
$("#foo").alertMe(function (x$) { return x$.width(); });
```

<sub>And for completeness I guess I should mention you could probably get away with an `eval`-based solution, looking something like `$("#foo").alertMe("$(this).text()")`, but `eval` is evil and I will neither write up nor condone such a solution. EDIT: oh, I see you have done so in an edit to your original post. Good job corrupting future generations ;)</sub>